# How to change width and overflow via console in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, swift, webview, console, overflow

I am a iOS developer and I need to change some parameters in my webView iOS applications via JavaScript.

I can change parameters easily in Safari WebInspector but I need to understand how I can change two parameters **via WebInspector console**.

I need to change width from 100 % to 200vw in _1Fm4m _1h2dM class
[image]
and
change overflow x to visible in app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `querySelector()` and `Object.assign()` to assign several styles at once:

```
Object.assign(document.querySelector('._1Fm4m._1h2dM').style, {width: '200vw', /* any number of styles you want here */}) && 1
```

`&& 1` in the ends prevents of output of the style object (some unwanted noise), so you will get only `1` as output.

The same approach you use for your second case with `#app`.

```
Object.assign(document.querySelector('#app').style, {overflowX: 'visible'}) && 1
```

To avoid typing this every time you can define a function in the console:

```
const setStyle = (selector, style) => Object.assign(document.querySelector(selector).style, style) && 1;
```

and then use it:

```
setStyle('._1Fm4m._1h2dM', {width: '200vw'});
```

[image]

The more persistent approach would be adding your function to a snippet and run the snippet (Ctrl + Enter) before using `setStyle()`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works via console, I have one more question, for SWIFT I use webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_2Ts6i 3RGKj 318SY')[0].style.maxWidth='50%'") - document.getElementsByClassName and when I  am trying to change width like this -webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_1Fm4m _1h2dM')[0].style.width='200vw'") it is not working do know why?

Comment: @AntonyCatcher first make sure that the elements are found, try to console.log them:  `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('_2Ts6i 3RGKj 318SY'))` and check whether they are found

Comment: @AntonyCatcher if you find my answer useful you could accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up). that way i'll rewarded and motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_1Fm4m _1h2dM')[0].style.width='200vw'") it doesn't work but  webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_1Fm4m _1h2dM')[0].style.width='220%'") works but incorrect in SWIFT but webInspector show me correct layout with 200vw I don't understand why? could you help me please? yes I will accept you answer for sure thank for cooperation

Comment: @AntonyCatcher that's a problem with your CSS , not JS or Swift